# Difference between braces {} and brackets () in shell scripting

Tags: shell, brackets, braces

We use braces `{}` for variable expression like

```
NAME="test"

FILE_NAME=${NAME}file
```

But I don't understand in which scenarios we use brackets ()
Say `nslookup $(hostname)` works only with `()` brackets.

Can someone explain?

Comment: In US English, these: `()` are parentheses, and these: `[]` are brackets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Minor nitpick first:

- Brackets `[]`
- Parentheses `()`
- Braces `{}`
- (Double) Quotation marks `""`
- (Single) Quotation marks (apostrophes) `''`
- Backticks ``` `` ``` (Same as the tilde ~ key)

Braces are used in BASh scripts for complex variable expansion. Consider string concatenation:

```
STR="hello"
STR2=$STR
```

`STR2` evaluates to "hello". What if you wanted to make it something like "helloWorld". Doing something like `STR2="$STR2World"` won't work, so you use braces, ie: `STR2="${STR}World"`.

As for brackets, they are used, similar to the backtick, `, which expands the text between them as the text output from a command.

What if you wanted to store the current time as a string?

```
STR2=$(date)
```

Now `STR2` stores the string "Thu May  7 09:32:06 PDT 2015".

[**Additionally**, you can use parentheses to execute something in a subshell,](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) which will potentially affect your environment, PID, etc. Very useful for cases where you want a "throwaway" environment with having to track/restore environment variables, directories via `pushd`/`popd` instead of `cd`, etc.

Comment: I believe these `()` are commonly called "brackets" in UK English.

Comment: @KeithThompson From what I've found, you appear to by correct. Parentheses are called brackets, or to be more explicit, "circle brackets", while `[]` are always explicitly called "square brackets" in UK English. http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.ca/2006/08/parentheses-and-brackets.html

Comment: If you are gonna nitpick then backticks aren't the same as the tilde key on all keyboard layouts. Not every programmer runs an English keyboard, seeing as many countries have their own standard.

Comment: @Gemtastic Given that [English is the lingua franca on all SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), I think it's fair by extension to assume English language keyboards.

Comment: It actually isn't since English is an international language. Every latin-based language (that I know of) can type English without the need to swap keyboards.

Comment: @Gemtastic We should start a meta post on US/101 keyboards (and their derivatives) being de facto standards amongst the primary SO audience, or at least the largest cross-section of the SO community.

Comment: I find it a little easier to think of `${foo}` as the *canonical* way to expand parameters, and that `$foo` is an example of a special case where the braces can be dropped it doing so doesn't create an ambiguity.

Comment: @chepner Good point. I personally use the brace-notation you described as the default out of habit. Easier to code when the style is consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Using parentheses `(` executes something.  There happens to be a program named hostname - so $(hostname) will execute it.

try `which hostname` to see where that program resides